# SwiftUI Navigation for iPad, how does it work?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui

Im learning SwiftUI and have a question about creating a navigation between views for iPad. I see a lot tutorials online but showing small mobile devices, but not a lot addressing the iPad navigation theory and examples.

**--- PART 1**
I have a basic app that I have a "Previous" and "Next" buttons that need to navigate to the next OR previous page/view. I tried using the NavigationView/NavigationLink route and doesn't seem to work well on iPads - as per an article I read.

Would anyone have some resources or perhaps an example I can study to understand how it is applied.

**--- PART 2**
In addition, I would like to create a drawer slide out menu. Does anyone have any reference resources I can look at for this as well.

Thanks a lot all.

[image]

Sample Code:
When I run the simulator and click Next Page nothing happens. I have another view in which the struct is called page_2, but yet it doesn't navigate to it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         ZStack {
            Image("iPad-bg")
                  .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                  .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack() {
                  HStack(alignment: .top) {
                     Spacer()
                     Button(action: {}) {
                        Image("menu-btn")
                              .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                              .frame(width: 70.0, height: 70.0)
                              .padding(.trailing)
                     }
                     .padding(.top, -65)
                  }
                  Image("pg1-img1")
                     .padding(.top, -20.0)
                  HStack {
                     Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("Previous Page")
                           .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                     }
                     .padding(.vertical, 5.0)
                     .frame(width: 150.0)
                     .background(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.10, blue: 0.21))
                     .cornerRadius(5.0)
                  Spacer()
                     NavigationLink(destination: page_2()){
                        Button(action: {}) {
                           Text("Next Page")
                              .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 5.0)
                        .frame(width: 150.0)
                        .background(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.10, blue: 0.21))
                        .cornerRadius(5.0)
                     }                     
                  }
                  .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
                  Spacer()
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that questions including more than one question are considered of topic on SO.

Comment: `I tried using the NavigationView/NavigationLink` So please show what you have tried so far. Where did you struggle? What didn´t work as expected?

Comment: Thanks burnsi. I have added some sample code and what is happening when I run the simulation, which is nothing. The button clicks but doesnt navigate to the specified view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a `NavigationLink` like that. If you want a `NavigationLink` that looks like a Button you can use something like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: page_2()){
    Text("Next Page")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
}
.buttonStyle(.plain) // this is the important part
.padding(.vertical, 5.0)
.frame(width: 150.0)
.background(Color(red: 0.09, green: 0.10, blue: 0.21))
.cornerRadius(5.0)
```

As a tip: It would be better to break this View up into multiple SubViews. This will not only improve performance while coding, it will allow you to reason better about your code.

Comment: This worked burnsi. Thank you. So in essence its very similar to a smaller device, meaning the way it is coded.

Comment: @Sergio Most of the time it is the same.

Comment: Cool cool. And Im assuming tackling a slide drawer menu would be the same as for smaller device. Ive seen a bunch of tutorials and guides but mainly iPhones.

Comment: It looks like as Im going back and forth through the pages, its stacking/nesting the 
< Back native navigation on the top left. Any way to completely remove those and any reference to it?

Comment: I figured out how to hide the native navigation bar and seemed to fix the issue.